# Android Broadcast Receiver not waking up application when registered dynamically

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a situation where I only want to register a `BroadcastReceiver` for Time changed on certain platforms.  For performance reasons, I would like to register the receiver dynamically via the `context.registerReceiver` method only on the platforms needed. I can detect the platform on app first run and decide if I would like to listen to this event.

While testing this approach I have found that when registering via `context.registerReceiver` the application will not be woken up if the process is not running.

Is this expected and is there a setting to get around it?

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED); 
this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("MYTAG", "Received Broadcast from dyn one");


        }
    }, filter);
```

Comment: provide some code maybe?

Comment: Added some code ... looks like from what @silk states below it may not be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your broadcast registered dynamically you can receive messages only when your application is running. If you want it to wake up you need to declare your broadcast in manifest

Comment: Is this documented anywhere or just from observation?

Comment: I've read this in Reto Meier's book which is considered as information from first hands.

Answer (score 2):

A dynamically registered receiver has a short lifetime so it wont wake up your device always. You have to declare it in your Manifest if you want it to behave they way you need!

P.S.: Had exactly the same problem recently so i am pretty sure for this!